# Return Bad Request on validation when body contains extra fields

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

Is there a way within asp.net core, jsonserializer or FluentValidation to return a **400 Bad Request** on POST/PATCH/PUT if the body contains extra fields that are not part of the model used for this method.

A little example (c#):

```
public class UserDataObject {
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

as json

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow"
}
```

So the above json is fine, but we want to return a 400 Bad Request if we would receive a body like that

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow",
  "extra": "data"
}
```

There is no property *Extra* on the model

Do we need to dig deeper into the jsonserializer, to validate the body details or is there some extension point in the framework to handle such a case.

We are using json-bodies for simplicity and FluentValidation to validate models.

Comment: You can try to use [Resource filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#resource-filters), they are executed before model binding, so you can check an existance of additional fields. If you afraid of too big input json body, you can limit it's size.

Comment: How are you planning to receive POST data from client, in raw json string or are you using Model binding?

Comment: The model binder and/or something like `JsonConvert` will simply discard anything extra, so it's not strictly an error to include unnecessary, extra stuff in a JSON request body. If you really want to enforce this, then you'll likely need custom middleware or a resource filter as @SlavaUtesinov suggested, but there really is no need for this.